# Regex string replacement ends too soon in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am using PowerShell (5.1) and am trying to encode a string before I pass it in the URL, to a REST API. The API users certain characters (e.g. a colon (`:`) means "equal") when used between a property and its value. If a colon (for example) appears in the value portion, then it should be replaced with the URL-safe encoding (`%3A`).

The following PowerShell works when the string is `filter=username:"user1@domain.com"`. The `@` symbol is replaced with `%40`. However, if the string is, `filter=username:"user1@domain.com"|"user2@domain.com"`, then only the first `@` is replaced.

The PowerShell snipet looks like this:

```
$Filter = 'filter=username:"user1@domain.com"'
$pattern1 = '[^a-zA-Z\d\s]' # Match any non-alpha numeric or white space character.
$pattern2 = '(?:>:|<:|:|>|<|!:|:|~|!~|@)(?:")(.*?)(?:")' # Allow us to replace characters in the filter. We will leave some of the characters alone, since they are used by the API in certain spots. For example, ":" means equal between the property name and value but should be replaced in the value portion of the pair.
$regex = [Regex]::new($pattern2)
$regex.Matches($Filter) | ForEach-Object {
    $Filter = $Filter -replace ([regex]::Escape($_.Groups[1].value)), ([uri]::EscapeDataString($_.Groups[1].value))
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Use: `[Uri]::EscapeDataString('username:"user1@domain.com"|"user2@domain.com"')`

Comment: I cannot, because the value of $Filter is not known ahead of time.

Comment: I updated the original post, to make it more clear.

Comment: `Filter = 'filter=username:"user1@domain.com"` is not a correct PowerShell syntax, please create a workable [mcve] and be clear on the input sample(s) (is it really a string or an array of strings?, where do the user ids come from?). Also supply one or more expected outputs and actual output(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unclear on the exact requirements, but perhaps the following does what you want:

```bash
# Sample string to transform.
$filter = 'filter=username:"user1@domain.com"|"user2@domain.com"' 

[regex]::Replace(
  $filter,
  '(?<=[:|><~@]").*?(?=")',
  {
    param($m)
    [Uri]::EscapeDataString($m.Value)
  }
)
```

This relies on all property values being enclosed in `"..."` (and having no escaped *embedded* `"`) and being preceded by any one of the following chars.: `: | < > ~ @`

Result (only the property values inside `"..."` substrings were URI-escaped):

```bash
filter=username:"user1%40domain.com"|"user2%40domain.com"
```

For an explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/1PziwI/2).

---

As for **what you tried**:

The only thing missing from your regex is a `\|` segment so as to also match a verbatim `|` before a property value's opening `"` (inserted before `|@`):

```bash
(?:>:|<:|:|>|<|!:|:|~|!~|\||@)(?:")(.*?)(?:")
```

See [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/OvjHmF/1).

However, note that your regex can be simplified, by using character sets (`[...]`) and removing redundant parts:

```bash
(?:[:|><~@](?:")(.*?)(?:")
```

This simplified form is used in the solution above, albeit via using *lookaround assertions* so that no capture group is necessary.